# VueJS + mixin / prototypes

Tags: vuejs2, prototype, mixins

I need to have a list of various methods on numbers, tables ...

Simple example of a method: nearest(), find the closest elements in a table to a past value.

- array: [0, 3, 6, 9, 11]
- value: 7
- return = 6

I thought to make a mixin for each type, or possibly a plugin. However I can also make a .js file and make a list of prototypes.

ex: array.prototype.nearest ()

What do you think is the best solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you make either separate classes, or use prototypes. That way, your functions would also be available for use outside of vue components.

If you have functions that specifically relate to components, or which require data that is only available inside components (e.g. vuex state), yes, by all means make a plugin or a mixin.